# Generate a GUID in AIR 3?

Tags: apache-flex, air

AIR 3.0 has the ability to create real GUIDs.  I just can't figure out how.

http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/10/secure-data-persistence-with-air-3.html

There's Christian Cantrell describing that it's possible and maybe with the help of generateRandomBytes
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/crypto/package.html

I don't know how to turn random bytes into a guid though.  Does anyone know how to create GUIDs in AIR 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use [createUID()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/UIDUtil.html#createUID%28%29) from the [UIDUtil class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/UIDUtil.html)?

If not; will this [blog](http://gehanmax.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-create-guid-in-flex-as3.html) post help?

Comment: I think the createUid will now create a GUID.

Comment: @Nate Based on the docs; it does look like the createUID() is in in the GUID format.  Does this answer your question, or were you looking for more-or different--information?

Comment: It took me a while to find, but in newer Air versions this function now belongs to a different class:RPCUIDUtil.createUID. Package: mx.utils. I also had to reference  <AIRSDK>/frameworks/libs/air/aircore.swc in a flex project to be able to use it.